# For Loops, XHRs, Scope

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm really stuck with what maybe a scoping issue. Can anyone here please help me find fault with this snippet?

So I have something called surveys that are associated with a questiongroup. And i'm trying to loop through surveys to get data about the associated questiongroup except I'm really lost on where I should scope a question group.

The first function in snippet below logs qg as 'undefined' returned from the second function.

```
function loadData() {
  var params = {};
  var surveyURL = "surveys/";
  var surveys, qg;
  var survey_ids = [];
  // this below calls the URL 
  var $surveyXHR = klp.api.do(surveyURL, params);
  // this below is essentially $.ajax.done()
  $surveyXHR.done(function(data) {
    surveys = data["features"];
    for(var each in surveys) {
      qg = getSurveysQuestionGroup(surveys[each]["id"]);
      console.log(qg);
      // surveys[each]["created_by"] = qg["created_by"]["first_name"]
    }
    console.log(surveys);
  });

}

function getSurveysQuestionGroup (surveyId) {
  var params = {};
  var qg;
  var qgURL = "surveys/"+ surveyId + "/questiongroups/";
  var $qgXHR = klp.api.do(qgURL, params); 
  $qgXHR.done(function(data) {
        qg= data["features"];
        //console.log(qg);
        return(qg);
  });
}
```

Comment: Start by getting rid of the for loop. Without the for loop, how would you get data for each of the surveys?

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding how ajax works.  Your function `getSurveysQuestionGroup` could be rewritten like this:

```
function getSurveysQuestionGroup (surveyId) {
  var params = {};
  var qg;
  var qgURL = "surveys/"+ surveyId + "/questiongroups/";
  var $qgXHR = klp.api.do(qgURL, params); 
  $qgXHR.done(processQgXHR);
  return; // THIS is what you are getting back in loadData!
}

function processQgXHR(data) {
  var qg = data["features"];
  return(qg); // not being used!
}
```

You'll need to refactor your code.  Ideally, you want to take action from *inside* the ajax callback function itself, **not** using return values.  Ajax and return values typically don't mix well.

If you're familiar with multi-threaded programming, think of an ajax request as creating a new thread, not a function call.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Initially I had this, but surveys seem to go out of scope inside the ajax.done functions. So i understand that an ajax call is async and spins off on its own. But I want to build the dependency that, for each survey, I get the question group and after that call completes I add some data into the survey. And then move to the next. However with this code below: a) The calls complete at random times, I also tried using $.ajax.always() b) The Survey object goes out of scope within the questiongroup ajax.done() call.  I am just not getting my head around this. If someone could suggest a structure for these nested calls, I'd be happy to follow.

```
function loadData() {
  var params = {};
  var surveyURL = "surveys/";
  var $surveyXHR = klp.api.do(surveyURL, params);
  $surveyXHR.done(function(data) {
    var surveys = data["features"];
    for(var each in surveys) {
      var qgURL = "surveys/"+ surveys[each]['id'] + "/questiongroups/";
      params = {}
      var $qgXHR = klp.api.do(qgURL, params); 
      $qgXHR.done(function(data) {
        var qg = data["features"][0]; //Change this later when we have active filter
        surveys[each]["created_by"] = qg["created_by"]["first_name"] + ' ' + qg["created_by"]["last_name"],
        var qURL = qgURL + qg["id"] + "/questions";
        var $qXHR = klp.api.do(qURL, params);
        $qXHR.done(function(data) {
          var questions = data["features"];
          surveys[each]['questions'] = questions;
        });
      });
      console.log(surveys[each]);
    }
  });
}
```